# Best Practices for Downloadable Free Guide Pages

Tags: forms, info-visualisation, ux-writing

My company wants to increase leads through free guides whereby a user completes a form and is then given access to downloadable content.

The page features information of what is in the guide and a form the user is required to complete before given access. Currently the form is featured on the page, we have tested gated content where the form pops up mid way through scrolling and has not achieved positive results.

I have been struggling to look for UX best practice/case studies/examples in this particular method of lead gen. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> This is a car. It has:
>
> - An engine, which runs on diesel
> - Four doors, two on each side
> - Four wheels, one in each corner
> - Many people have gotten one and say they like it
>
> Want to try it out and see if this is a car for you? Well, I want something from you first.

Does this sound familiar?

Susan Weinschenk talks about this in her book Neuro Web Design: What Makes Them Click. (I don't have the book at me at the moment so I'll fill in the details later.)

She compares these situations to a gift-giving. When you give someone a gift they start to feel they are in debt to you. In this state people are more willing to give something back and in your case this is information about themselves.

So instead of asking people to pay (with their information) beforehand, ask them to pay after they have had the change to read the guide. For example on the download page you can offer them more assistance on the matters the guide is about.

If people found your guides useful, now they also remember that you didn't force them to divulge personal information to get the guide. Because of this they have a positive image about your company and probably you are high on the list when they really have the need to buy something you sell.

Comment: Thanks locationunknown, really interesting take. The users will be taken to a free guides page via email, the aim is to convert users who access the page through the email. At that point, the page needs to sell why this guide will benefit the user, I think the page is too informative on what is in the guide and not why the guide will benefit the user e.g. speed of understanding. I have been researching lead magnet pages best practice which has given me a better understand of what elements resonate better with users and how to optimise the communication. May struggle with buy in not asking b4.